# Swing creating a tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using Swing and trying to create another tabbed pane for my GUI. I searched online and found examples, but when I try it out the new tabbed pane is not created. I pasted my tabbed pane code below, thank you

```
layout = new FormLayout("p,6dlu,p,3dlu,p,10dlu:grow", "p,3dlu,p,3dlu,p,3dlu,p,3dlu,p,10dlu,p,3dlu,p,3dlu,p,3dlu,p,3dlu");
formBuilder = new DefaultFormBuilder(layout);

cc = new CellConstraints();
formBuilder.setBorder(Borders.DLU4_BORDER);

tab = new JTabbedPane();
tab.add("New", formBuilder.getPanel());
```

Comment: How do you add tab component? Did you tried to replace it with JLabel and check that label is visible?

Comment: You can also check its size and visibility flag in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a tabbed pane:

Declare The tabs:

```
    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    Panel chat = new Panel();
    Panel vrage = new Panel();
    tabs.add("Chat", chat);
    tabs.add("Questions", vrage);
```

Declare the top Panel

```
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.add(tabs);
```

Add The top Panel to JFrame

```
    trFrame.add(topPanel);
```